# Why is my XML http request returning HTML instead of JSON?

Tags: json, webdriver, saucelabs

I need to obtain the JSON response text from a web page in order to parse it. However, when I create my XML HTTP request, I get HTML returned that's not even from the page I've requested.

I've verified that the content-type is set to application/json, required  xmlhttprequest instead of xhr2 (did not work), set XMLHttpRequest.responseType to "json", and more. I tried a different url (https://jsonplaceholder.typicode.com/todos/1) and I'm able to obtain my JSON response text. However, with my "secret URL" (unable to provide unfortunately), I get an HTML response.

I'm not sure where I get the HTML from, I looked on SauceLabs, but it fails at this point. I also tried browser.getURL(), but I get a

```
function myXMLRequest() {

  var XMLHttpRequest = require('xhr2');
  XMLHttpRequest.responseType = "json";
  var xmlhttp = new XMLHttpRequest(); 
  // this URL works, but my secret URL does not
  var url = "https://jsonplaceholder.typicode.com/todos/1";

  xmlhttp.onreadystatechange = function() {
    console.log("this.readyState: " + this.readyState + " 
    this.status: " + this.status);
  if (this.readyState === 4 && this.status === 200) {
      console.log("this.responseText: " + this.responseText);
  } else {
      console.log("I was not ready");
  }
  };
      xmlhttp.open("GET", url, true);
      xmlhttp.send();
    }
```

In the URL that works, I get a response text like:

```
{
  "userId": 1,
  "id": 1,
  "title": "delectus aut autem",
  "completed": false
}
```

I would like my secret URL to obtain a response like this. Currently it obtains an HTML response, as can be seen from my image.

[image: HTML response]

Comment: You are setting the static property of `XMLHttpRequest.responseType` which does not exist. Try setting `xmlhttp.responseType` instead, otherwise it will default to `text`.

Comment: Thank you @ZorgoZ. I fixed that. Unfortunately, it still results in the same issue.

Answer (score 0):

Your secret URL only directs to a redirect page.

In your XML http request you need to specify the final URL -> probably the one in the form action (in your image).

Comment: That's the weird thing. My secret URL does not redirect me anywhere, and has a 200 response code, not a 302, etc. I assume it's redirecting me somewhere, but I don't know why or how it's able to do that. Regardless, setting the final, secret URL is what takes me to the image. It did not do that previously.